# unable to open port in Qt 5.0.2

Tags: qt, serial-port, port, qextserialport

I am designing a real time application on Qt. got stuck in QExtserialport 
the design has hardware part which sense and send signal through UART communication. I design application to display GUI interface. the following code not open port in Qt. but it does on Minicom, cutecom display value's.

HeadeFile.h

```
INCLUDEPATH += .
include(..project/qextserialport-1.2rc/src/qextserialport.pri)

CONFIG += extserialport
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
Qextserialport *rs232_;
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
rs232_ = new QextSerialPort("/dev/ttyS0");
rs232_->open( QIODevice::ReadWrite );
if (!rs232_->isOpen()) {
    qDebug()<<"....Port ttyS0 CanNot Open...."<<endl
}
rs232_->setBaudRate(BAUD4800);
rs232_->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
rs232_->setParity(PAR_ODD);
rs232_->setDataBits(DATA_8);
rs232_->setStopBits(STOP_1);

QTimer *s2_timer = new QTimer(this);
s2_timer->setInterval(17);
s2_timer->start();

connect(rs232_, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onDataAvailable()));
```

it always display "Port ttyS0 CanNot Open"

Comment: If you can switch to QtSerialPort, this would not probably b an issue for you? Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated Qt to 5.6, solved by QtSerialPort.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html